# Windows XP issue (MSConfig, BIOS, and DOS may be involved)

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Here is my issue. Me, being the spoon I am, decided to use MSConfig to get windows to always boot to safe mode, because I was having issues with the windows activation protocall. I had also checked the alternate shell option along with **SAFEBOOT**. Now, since my copy of windows isn't activated yet, if won't let me log on period. I can't get back to MSConfig now. Is there a way to revert these changes?

Comment: Can you describe what happens when you start the computer? And after it's started, what do you see? Do you have a prompt or something else? Do you have a bootdisk?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg it starts normally. When I try to log in, since I am in safe mode on alternate shell, it pops up a dialog box saying that I can't log in until I activate it, and I can't get to MSConfig.

Comment: Do you have the Win XP installation disk? If you install/repair Windows XP on top of your existing installation, it should rewrite your erroneous file as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change that MSConfig applied is likely by adding the `/SAFEBOOT` argument into the boot.ini file on the boot drive as an argument to the kernel.

Fortunately, because it is Windows XP, this is a text file, and to change it you just need to be able to get to it.

The first option is to boot from a Windows XP Installation CD and use the Recovery Console.  From the recovery console, it should be possible to navigate to where the boot.ini file lives (which is likely in the root of the first partition), and `type` the contents to confirm the issue.  If you put a USB stick into the machine before booting, you should be able to `copy` the boot.ini onto the USB stick, edit the file with another computer, then `copy` it back over the original.

An alternative is to use one of a variety of Linux boot CDs or live CDs (or bootable USB sticks).  This should allow you to boot to a Linux command prompt or desktop, at which point you can `mount` the NTFS boot partition from the hard drive, and use a text editor from the Linux environment to edit the file.  Exactly how you go about doing each of these steps will vary slightly from Linux distribution to Linux distribution based on what tools they come with.  Something such as OpenSUSE or Debian is likely to have all the tools needed.

A final option is to remove the hard drive from this machine, and attach it to another machine as a second drive (or using a USB hard drive adapter).  The second machine will then be able to see the partitions on the drive, and you can use a text editor to get the boot.ini file.

Once you are able to edit the boot.ini file, you probably want to copy the entry in the `[Operating Systems]` section onto another line, then edit it to remove the /SAFEBOOT option.

For example, change:

```
[operating systems] 
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Windows XP Professional" /fastdetect /SAFEBOOT
```

... to ...

```
[operating systems] 
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Windows XP Professional" /fastdetect /SAFEBOOT
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Windows XP Professional Normal" /fastdetect
```

Once you have done this, boot into XP again, and you should get an option during boot to select one of the two options, either the previous SAFEBOOT option, or the normal boot.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to hook the drive up to another computer, but could you provide the filepath for the boot.ini file?

Comment: Typically it'll be in the root folder on the boot drive, or in a folder in the root called "boot".  If you have lots of partitions on the drive, you'll have to work out which is the boot one, but start with the first one.

Comment: If the second machine is a Windows machine, you can use the `Disk Management` tool in the `Computer Management` program to see the partitions and which drive they're in (right-click My Computer and select Manage).

Comment: Hey, I still might need the file location. I tried looking in C:/Windows and C:/Windows/Boot, but I didn't find it. Is there a specific file location, or am I missing something?

Comment: It should just be in the root drive of C:\.  I forgot to mention that it may well be 'hidden', so you'll need to set the 'Show all Files' option.  I'll see if I can find an article describing how to edit the file manually.

Comment: I already have all hidden files and folders displayed though.... but i'll look there.

Comment: I didn't find anything.... heres a picture https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q7IvzHrEutAbKf888kQ1wwkiXrHWixjU

Comment: @EgMusic If you've hooked this drive up to another machine, then surely the C: drive you posted is the C: drive of the other machine, not the hard drive you connected?  They can't both be called "C:".  The screenshot is of a Vista or above machine because there's a `Users` folder where as XP used `Documents and Settings`.  Check the other drives on the machine for a `Documents and Settings`?  Maybe post a screenshot of `Disk Management` that I mentioned above.

Comment: I haven't been able to connect the hard drive to another computer yet, but I tried looking on another computer for reference.